# FontLab Studio and font editing

Tags: fonts

I trying to editing some font using FontLab Studio 5.1 but when i have finished and i save the work, one time that i have close the program and i try to reopen the .otf file, it is remained at the older version without any change. Is Python needed?

Comment: Obvious suggestion (I've done it many times): if you used Save As, these programs sometimes put it in some other directory because you forgot to specify where and they remembered something else.

Comment: Thanks !, ok i have save the file and now it take the changes, but with the command save as i can only save in .vbf and if i try to rename the file in filename.otf and make save as it give this error: "[WARNING] <LMMath-Regular> Use of DFLT tag has been deprecated. It will work, but please use 'dflt' instead." When i use the font, the editor (texmakerx) it give me this other error: "Font \l_tmpb_font has only 8 fontdimen parameters \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}"

Comment: Sorry, but this question is somewhat off-topic for this site.

Comment: I flagged this question for migration to [graphicdesign.se].